# NSTablewView, Highlight Mode "None" and Blurred Background

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsvisualeffectview

I have noticed that when my view-based `NSTableView` has the `highlight` attribute set to **"Source List"** in Interface Builder, it renders its background with the **vibrance effect** (i.e., it blurs what lies behind its parent window).

If instead I you set said attribute to **"None"** or **"Regular"** (the other two options), the `background color` attribute is automatically set to white, and at runtime its rendered **opaque** (even if a custom color with an alpha of less than 1.0 is specified).

I need my table cells to be non-highlightable, but I would really like the blur effect.

Also, I can't afford disallowing cell highlighting via the NSTableViewDelegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool
```

...because that makes the text fields inside my cells unselectable and thus uneditable.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352869/disable-nsvisualeffectview-in-source-list-nstableview), which basically asks for the *opposite* solution (i.e., disable vibrance when highlight is set "Source List"), so following the answers there I tried this code on the view controller that hosts my table view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.

    let appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight)
    tableView.appearance = appearance
}
```

*(appearance is instantiated and assigned in two separate lines to confirm it is non-nil on the debugger)*

...but it doesn't change anything.

**Is there any easy workaround?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder, I had to do three things:

1. Give the **scroll view** that contains the table view a transparent background color.
2. Uncheck "Draw Background" for the scroll view.
3. Give the table view a transparent background color.

…then I was able to see the `NSVisualEffectView` that I'd placed the table inside.